Google cloud storage return old images
I have a public bucket, uploading the images through a React web app using a signed url:
export const uploadFile = (policy: PostPolicy, file: File): Promise<void> => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (const field in policy.fields) {
    const value = policy.fields[field];
    value && formData.append(field, value);
  }
  formData.append("file", file);

  return fetch(policy.url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }).then();
};

The PostPolicy is the result of the call to bucket.GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4. The upload and retrieving work, but once the image is updated, the browser seems to cache the old file, for a long time, and I am not able to edit this caching. I already tried´to user the gcloud-cors-settings adding maxAgeSeconds:
[
  {
    "maxAgeSeconds": 10,
    "method": ["POST", "GET"],
    "origin": ["http://localhost:50030"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Cache-Control"]
  }
]


Did not help. I tried to add the 'Cache-Control' header:

export const uploadFile = (policy: PostPolicy, file: File): Promise<void> => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (const field in policy.fields) {
    const value = policy.fields[field];
    value && formData.append(field, value);
  }
  formData.append("file", file);

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=15");

  return fetch(policy.url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: formData,
  }).then();
};

I don't get any error, but the header is ignored.
How can I fix this problem?

As mentioned in this document

By default, publicly readable objects are served with a Cache-Control header allowing such objects to be cached for 3600 seconds. If you need to ensure that updates become visible immediately, you should set a Cache-Control header of "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" on such objects. For help doing this, see gsutil help setmeta.

Also as stated here

There's no way to set a default Cache-Control header on newly uploaded files. It either needs to be set explicitly (by setting the header) at the time the object is written, or after the upload by updating the object's metadata using something like the gsutil command.


Hi, thanks for the help, but i am not using the API, i am using the Signed Urls. Furthermore, as you can see in my question, I already tried to set the Cache-Control Header.

Can you have a look at the updated answer

As already mentioned, I do as explained, but it does not work. In the Google Cloud console I dont see the cache set and the image displayed still stays the old one.

After almost a week I decided to add ?t=${new Date().getTime()} as a hack.

Also check this link which might help

Yes, that's exactly the workaround every one is using. However, I a wondering why it is not working as it should, based on what written in the documentation.

you mean gsutil command not working as expected?Ensure that the metadata has been set correctly. Use the following gsutil command to check the metadata of the file gsutil ls -L gs://your-bucket-name/your-file-name

Look for the Cache-Control field in the output to confirm it has been set to private, max-age=0, no-transform. Also try this

Sorry, I wrote several times I am using signed urls, no API and no gsutil.

As per this link unfortunately seems to be not possible, as cache is not in GCS but in local browser of the user or somewhere in the internet, out of GCS control. maybe you have to use the workaround adding timestamp to the url or use the md5hash of the file as the name
